# Time sync between windows xp and windows 7?

Tags: time, synchronization

Hi i'm trying to do a time sync between windows xp and windows 7 machines. windows XP is my back office server and i have 4 windows 7 machines that are my controllers. The windows 7 machines are not connected to the internet. All the windows 7 machines must be synced to Windows XP host server. Can anyone suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816042 may be relevant (turning the Windows XP computer into a NTP server). You may also want to search how to make the Windows 7 computers use those for time syncing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     1)Login into any windows 7 as Administrator user and make sure the XP is       pingable using the hostname 
            **Ping xphostname**   
     2)Check if the following command works 
      **net time \\xphostname**
    If you are able to see the time of the XP box then proceed with Step 3.     If not perform the following steps
     a) Add the Ip and hostname of the XP in the  **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** file of the Windows 7 and vice versa.

   3)In the windows 7, open notepad with Administrator privileges and create a new file and type the following and save the file as synctime.bat.
              ***NET TIME \\xphostname /SET /YES***
   4)Create a shortcut of the synctime.bat file in the startup folder.
   5)To sync the time every day, we need to schedule a task using task scheduler
        **Start --- > Search --- >Task Scheduler** 
   6)Create a new task 

   7)Name the task “whatever you wish to name” in the General tab and do the following in the Security Options portion
 i)Select Run whether user is logged on or not
 ii)Select Run with highest Privileges
 iii)Select the OS as Windows 7 in the configure for Option


   8)Select Triggers tab
  i)Create a new trigger to create a daily schedule.
  ii)Select On a Schedule in Begin the task drop down and configure a daily schedule you want to run the time sync (Preferably 12:00 AM)
  iii)Check Enabled in the bottom.
  iV)Create another trigger to execute on start up.
   v)Select At StartUp in Begin the task drop down.
   vi)Check Enabled in the bottom.


   9)Select Action tab
  i) Create a new action
  ii)In the program/script field browse the path to cmd application in     **C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**
  iii)In the arguments field, paste the path of the batch file created earlier(synctime.bat) .

   Press Ok. 

   To Test the Time Sync.
   Note: Try changing the time and date manually and restart the machine to see if the time sync is working.
```